# How to test Rspec For controller,

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

How to Rectify this error in RSpec for Controller,

1) SellersController GET index find the Activity
     Failure/Error: assigns(:activity).should eq([activity])

```
   expected: [#<Activity id: 65, transactable_type: "admin", transactable_id: 1, action_type: "seller", user_id: 1, is_approved: false, approved_by: nil, created_at: "2012-04-09 11:02:17", updated_at: "2012-04-09 11:02:17", associatable_type: nil, associatable_id: nil>]
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
```

Seller_rspec.rb

```
describe "GET index" do
    it "find the Activity" do
 activity = Activity.create!(:transactable_type=>"admin",:transactable_id=>1,:action_type=>"seller",:user_id =>1,:is_approved=>0)
     get :index,{:is_approved => activity.to_param,:user_id=>1,:approved_by=>"admin"}
     assigns(:activity).should eq([activity])
    end
```

In controller

```
 def index
        @activities=Activity.find(:all,:select => 'DISTINCT transactable_type,transactable_id,action_type,is_approved,approved_by',:conditions=>["is_approved= ?  and user_id=? and approved_by IS NULL",false,current_user.id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a code into controller which should go to the model. Create a method or scope in Activity model like:

```
def self.find_not_approved(current_user_id)
      find(:all,
           :select => 'DISTINCT transactable_type,transactable_id,action_type,is_approved,approved_by',
           :conditions= ["is_approved= ?  and user_id=? and approved_by IS NULL",
           false,
           current_user_id])
end
```

So you can just have in controller (I've made up the method name):

```
  def index
    @activities = Activity.find_not_appoved(current_user.id)
  end
```

And just to *anser* your question, it should be `assigns(:activities).should eq([activity])` not `assigns(:activity).should eq([activity])` - as your are checking @activities variable in controller not, @activity.